# Largest subgroup of a group $G$ excluding a particular element $w \neq e_G$?

Tags: group-theory

I think it's possible to construct a unique largest subgroup not containing a particular element. Do we know anything in particular about this subgroup?

Is there an existing construction that the largest subgroup not containing a particular element is equivalent to?

---

I'm curious about ways of taking an existing "highly composite" group like $S_n$ and producing a smaller one in a somewhat constructive way.

There's probably a way to formalize a notion of "compositeness" that places symmetric groups at the top of the pack, but I don't know the right definition.

By somewhat constructive what I mean is ... if I have some kind of concrete presentation of the group $G$ like generators and relations I want to be able to more or less directly write down generators and relations for the subgroup. I'm not requiring that the new presentation be "canonical", so there could be a redundant generator for instance. In other words, I want to be to compute things in the new group if I could compute things before.

---

Suppose I have a finite group $G$ . I pick a particular element $w \in G$ where $w \neq e_{\small{G}}$ for exclusion. Let $H$ be one of the co-largest subgroups of $G$ .

existence of $H$ :

let $S$ be the complete lattice of subgroups for $G$. Forget its lattice structure. Every $s \in S$ either contains $w$ or does not. In particular, $\langle e_{\small{G}} \rangle$ does not contain $w$ . Because $G$ and therefore $S$ is finite, we can inspect the elements of $S$ one at a time, and keep track of the largest elements containing $w$ we've seen as we traverse $S$ . At the end, we'll have a collection of co-largest elements of $S$ containing $w$ .

uniqueness of $H$ :

$S$ is a complete lattice and the contains $w$ relation respects the lattice structure in two ways.

$$ a \leq_S b \;\;\;\;\; a \ni w \implies b \ni w $$

A converse property also holds

$$ a \ni w \implies \exists\, l \,\leq_S\, a \;.\; l \ni w $$

Or, equivalently

$$ a \ni w \implies (a = w) \;\mathrm{xor}\; \left( \exists \,l \,\lt_S\, a \,.\, l \ni w \right) $$

Let $T$ be the sublattice of $S$ consisting only of the elements not containing $w$ .

$T$ is not empty since $\langle e \rangle \in T$ .

$T$ is closed under $\wedge_T \stackrel{df}{=} \wedge_S$ .

$$w \in a \;\;\mathrm{and}\;\; w \in b \iff w \in a \wedge_S b$$

$T$ is likewise closed under $\vee_T \stackrel{df}{=} \wedge_S$

This means that the union of all elements in $T$, $\max(T) = \bigcup_{t \in T} t$ is itself in $T$, and in $S$, and hence a unique subgroup of $G$ .

Is there another, more common construction, that gives us back a group from $G$ that's isomorphic to this one?

Comment: No, there is no unique largest such subgroup. Just try the example of any element of order $3$ in $S_3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you are using the lattice terminology and you talk about the lattice of subgroups so lets do some explanation:

In the latice of subgroups the $\wedge$ operator is simply the intersection $H\wedge K=H\cap K$.

But the $\vee$ operator **is not a union**. In fact $H\vee K=\langle H\cup K\rangle$ where $\langle\cdot\rangle$ stands for "generated by". Note that the set theoretic union of subgroups is **hardly ever** a subgroup and in fact the situation when it always is occures **only** in cyclic groups (where the lattice of subgroups is linear).

So your conclusion "$\max(T) = \bigcup_{t \in T} t$ is itself in $T$" is wrong, because (1) $\bigcup t$ is not even a subgroup and (2) $\max(T)=\langle\bigcup_{t\in T}t\rangle$ no longer has to be in $T$.

For example consider case when $G=\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$ and let $w=(1,0)$. Then take $H=\{(0,0), (1,1)\}$ and $K=\{(0,0), (0,1)\}$. Both are subgroups that don't contain $w$. And both are maximal in $G$. It follows that the only subgroup that contains both of them is the whole $G$. Meaning $\max(T)=G$ in your terminology and clearly $w\in\max(T)$.

In particular this also implies that $T$ is not a complete lattice.

So I'm very sorry to disappoint you but the concept is not really valid. But it's good to try new things, keep up the good work!